# Compound word for stale and able

Tags: meaning

I'm a programmer and I need a word meaning `stale` and `-able`.
I basically need to define an interface for those things which each can be `not staled` or `staled`.

Are `staleable` or `stalable` make any common sense even those words are not in dictionary?
Is there any synonyms for this meaning?

Comment: _Stale_ as a verb is rare, I think, and the word brings to mind perishable products like bread. Are you writing an interface for bread and cookies, or is it possible that you might find a better applicable verb? If you _do_ mean stale, why not indicate the opposite: a boolean StaysFreshForever?

Comment: *Perishable* extends the metaphor, but I think I'd just use "Can Be Stale", or *CanBeStale* if you need it to be a token. "CanBeX" is a common enough idiom in the context.

Comment: @oerkelens I believe the OP means "***stalled***" (two `L`s), which is why he's having a hard time finding adjectives in the dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, do you mean "stale" or "stall"?  Normally, I (a programmer for over 40 years) would use "blocked" rather than "stalled", and "ready" rather than "able", if I'm understanding your context at all.

Comment: What exactly do you want to convey by "stale?" The word *stale* is usually not applied to non-food items (except metaphorically), certainly not an interface.

Comment: The question should be closed as unclear, unless the OP chooses between *stale* and *stall*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming of programming variables, which is specifically off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the action that a user could take in a situation like this is to "mark" the item as stale. As such, I would suggest a phrase as the following:

> "If the user has marked this as stale, ..."

The compounds would not necessarily be immediately comprehensible.

Another approach would be to copy from Microsoft which uses the word "tombstoned" for this concept.  If the user account has been "tombstoned" the account is marked for deletion after a period of time. In the meantime, the record has been tombstoned, so that the record is known to be "stale."  The rcord itself is thus tombstonable, if that helps.

Comment: "Tombstone" is Microsoft's coinage? Are you sure?

Comment: Yeah, heard "tombstone" used in this sense before Microsoft was born.

Comment: Didn't say they invented it- but they did popularize it. At least for me.